Find the largest $a\times b$ lattice that can exist combinations of 2-colourings such that no rectangle with same coloured vertices exist
I came across this problem in contest math:
For a 2-colouring of an $a\times b$ lattice, find a sufficient relation between $a$ and $b$ such that there is a scenario where no rectangles with same coloured vertices and have sides that are horizontal and vertical exist.
Here's a graph for $3\times 6$ lattice:

For example, this is a $3\times 6$ lattice with no rectangles with same coloured vertices, and horizontal and vertical sides (known as monochromatic rectangles).
Problem asks for what relation does $a$ and $b$ have with each other in order to form these lattices that can exist these combinations of colourings such that no monochromatic rectangles exist.
I tried on my own to do it. I think for $a=3$ it is easy because there are only 8 combinations per row, excluding the all red or all blue ones we get a maximum of $b$ as $6$.
I also noticed that for $a\times b$ each column must have $\frac{a}{2}$ coloured lattices for even $a$, same for $b$. And for $a$ is odd each column either has $\frac{a+1}{2}$ or $\frac{a-1}{2}$ coloured lattices. Also for $a=2$, $b$ can reach infinity.
But doing these is not enough, the problem asks for a generalisation of the relation between $a$ and $b$. What if $a=4,5$ or higher? How high can it go, or how big the lattice can be?

Say red is the most common color. Count column pairs of red-red.  Reach a contradiction. $\quad$ For $ a\geq 6$, clearly $b \leq 3$. so what's the limit on $a$ if $b = 2$?

@CalvinLin $a$ can get to infinity because if $b=2$ then I can just colour all of the columns as one blue one red, and there will guarantee no rectangles however big $a$ is.

Ah, I see that now. I got distracted because the first part of the paragraph is not true, so I skipped reading. $\quad$ Note that it is not true that each column must have an even-ish number of red and blue cells. Of course, in the construction, one might want to implement that restriction because it could help reduce the chance of a rectangle.

Hint: Find a $4 \times 6$ and $ 5\times 5$ with no such rectangle. Show that any $ 4 \times 7$ and $ 5 \times 6$ will contain such a rectangle.  $\quad$ Then try this for 3 colors.

@CalvinLin I tried it with $5\times 4$, and monochromatic rectangles can be avoided. But it cannot be avoided with $5\times 5$. So I think it also cannot be avoided with $6\times 4$ lattices. The combinations are just too many!

@CalvinLin It's just two colours, I think a generalisation can be achieved for 2-colouring.

See also this question. Note also that whatever holds for an $a\times b$ rectangle also holds for a $b\times a$ rectangle.

In fact monochromatic rectangles can be avoided inside $4 \times 6$ (or $6 \times 4$) rectangles:  For each row of $4$, simply colour $2$ squares red, and $2$ squares blue, going through all $6$ possibilities on the $6$ rows.
Between, that, the comments, and the original question we have now covered every combination of $a$ and $b$.  To summarise:
If $a=2$ or $b=2$ then monochromatic rectangles can be avoided, by having every row (or column) of $2$ coloured blue-red or red-blue.
Also if $a\leq 4, b\leq 6$ or $a\leq 6, b\leq 4$ we can just restrict the above colouring of the $4 \times 6$ (or $6 \times 4$) rectangles, to avoid monochromatic rectangles.
These two sets of rectangles are the only ones which can avoid monochromatic rectangles.  Any other combination of $a,b$ will give a rectangle containing a $3\times 7$, $7 \times 3$ or $5\times 5$ rectangle.
To exclude $3\times 7$ (hence $7 \times 3$), we note as OP did that the rows (or columns) of 3 must be distinct - and there are only $6$ possibilities excluding a monochromatic row (or column) of $3$.  Given such a monochromatic row (or column) every other one will have at most one square of that colour, resulting in at most $5$ rows or columns (in fact at most 4).
This just leaves the $5\times 5$ rectangle. If one row has $2$ red and $3$ blue, then all other rows must have at least $2$ reds where the first row has blues.  This would give $5$ rows, but one of the rows would have all $3$ squares red, where the first row had blues.  Thus we would have a monochromatic red rectangle.  e.g.:
$$\begin{array}{ccccc} X&X&O&O&O\\
?&?&X&X&O\\
?&?&O&X&X\\
?&?&X&O&X\\
?&?&X&X&X\\
\end{array}$$
This just leaves every row having at least $4$ of one colour.  Thus we would have at least $3$ rows, with $4$ of the same colour.  Even with just $2$ such rows we would have a monochromatic rectangle.
